# Alternative to storing data in Threadlocal in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi-tenant application where each tenant has a value object which holds the settings for their site. These settings need to be collected from the DB and accessed from various places during each request. My question is, what is the proper way of storing and handling this kind of data?

My first thought was to store this object in a ThreadLocal and pull from it whenever I need to check against a particular setting (for example: `String val = SiteSettings.getSettings().getXXX();`), but I know this could be dangerous if you don't properly clear the ThreadLocal and the end of each request. Is there a better alternative to using ThreadLocals in this scenario?

Comment: I guess passing the object down to the places it's needed isn't a viable option?

Comment: Technically you could, but if the logic that needs the object is several layers down from where it's initialized, say the data access layer, you would possibly be passing that object into places where it's not needed.